# Sending a Flow Action Notification to a Single User

Tags: visual-workflow, recordtriggeredflow, custom-notification

I have been struggling with this for a while and I cannot seem to get it to work. I need to have a flow send a notification that an object has been created to the object owner. I can get most of it to work but when I need to assign the Recipient ID, it won't let me use User.Id even though the help documentation says it can.

Am I missing a step? I have tried making a collection, then filtering it to a single ID, to see if it will allow a collection but the debug errors out. I am still really new to Flows, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
Adding an image of the problem.
What you're seeing in the image is that the Record owner Id is not an available option in the notification recipient field. It continuously goes into additional submenus and never returns an ID of any user.
[image: View of the recipient ID menu options for Record Owner]

Comment: don't you want `$Record.OwnerId` ?

Comment: @Anne Jessup - Welcome to SFSE community. Can you please help to add more details about your flow (like snapshot of component which fails to execute and error message) and what is the error you're received for this matter?

Comment: Not sure if its because of it being a custom object, but OwnerId is not an option. I can select the object of owner, but when I look in to the options, it only gives me the objects related to the owner (Account, Role, Profile, Manager, contact, etc. Nothing from the actual object of the owner.
If it helps, we use Target X for Applications, and that is who I am trying to send a notification to, the Application Owner. Not sure if that plays a factor here.

Comment: @MohanrajSivalingam
Happy to send a screenshot. Can we chat through a DM maybe? What I am finding is that through the Recipient ID, I cannot actually get to any user.ID, just keeps going through loops of objects without an actual field to select onto. Happy to send screenshots through DMs.

Comment: Nope, I am asking please Edit your question and add the screenshot for this question. so that community members will know the issue very easily. Please blur the details if you have any important or confidential information before adding that screenshot.

Comment: @MohanrajSivalingam
Ok, I added a screenshot of what I am experiencing as well as a short description. Hopefully this helps. Let me know if you need more images. Happy to add more. Thanks so much for your assistance.

Comment: @AnneJessup Thanks for adding the screenshot. In that snapshot `TGTX_Application_Owner__c` lookup field is a related to any `Child` object? I mean Is this field related object is available as child as any other `std/custom` object (which is Master) and it's currently available in `Master detail` relationship?

Comment: @MohanrajSivalingam
So our org is structured that Contacts (aka Students) are the master record with "Application" as the child record. We don't use Leads or Opportunities, instead with work with Inquiries and Applications. So the structure is Accounts --> Contacts --> Inquiries And Applications (Child records to Contacts).
Does this help?